# "Вернуться на круги своя"

Tags: фразеология, фонетика

У меня два вопроса по этой фразе. Во-первых, интересно было бы узнать, почему именно "круги"? А во-вторых, как правильно поставить ударение: на крУги или на кругИ?
Спасибо за ответ заранее.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Первоисточник — Библия. В Ветхом Завете (Книга Екклесиаста, или Проповедника, гл. 1, ст. 6) говорится о ветре, для которого это КРУГОВОЕ спиралевидное движение и характерно: «Идет ветер к югу, и переходит к северу, кружится, кружится на ходу своем, и возвращается ветер на круги свои» (рус. пер.). 
Смысл выражения: нет ничего нового на земле, все повторяется. 
Иногда используется в ироническом смысле применительно ко всевозможной бюрократической волоките, к незавершенному делу, предприятию.

Энциклопедический словарь крылатых слов и выражений. — М.: «Локид-Пресс». Вадим Серов. 2003.

По поводу ударения. Словари дают одно ударение: "на крУги своЯ"

Хотя бывает, что употребляют и с другим ударением: например, в песне "Ветер перемен" из к/ф о Мэри Поппинс в припеве: "...Сотни лет все ветры возвращаются/ Hа кругИ своя..." (видимо ударением автор пожертвовал в пользу ритма и рифмы).

Comment: Могу только добавить, что ударение соответствует принятому в старославянском (и древнерусском) языке.